# Return simulation and radius value for Bubble Graph after applying nest() in D3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I refered to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPr60pexvEM) in YouTube to make a bubble graph. However, the author didn't use a nest function to group his data. After I pre-processed my data using nest() function, I don't know how to pass the value to a function called **radiusScale()** in my code. I was thinking maybe I should pass the value of

```
d3.entries(groupByAgeAndtime)[i]["value"]
```

to **radiusScale()**. 
Here is my code snippet for my problem.

```
var radiusScale = d3.scaleSqrt()
                        .domain([d3.min(Object.values(groupByAgeAndtime), function(d){
                              return d.mean_time_in_hospital;
                        }),d3.max(Object.values(groupByAgeAndtime), function(d){
                              return d.mean_time_in_hospital;
                        })])
                        .range([50,150]);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        console.log(d3.entries(groupByAgeAndtime)[i]["value"]);
    }

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("x",d3.forceX(width/2).strength(0.05))
    .force("y",d3.forceY(height/2).strength(0.05))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d){
        return radiusScale(d.mean_time_in_hospital) + 2;
    }))

    var circles = svg.selectAll(".artist")
    .data(groupByAgeAndtime)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class","artist")// the "artist" will transform into class name in HTML
    .attr("r", function(d){
        return radiusScale(Object.values(groupByAgeAndtime))
    })
    .attr("fill","lightblue")
    .on("click",function(d){
        console.log(d)
    })
```

This is the screenshot: [image: screenshot]for the thing I want to pass to the function **radiusScale**. I think after passing the correct value, the circle will appear immediately. If not, can anyone tell me what is the value I should pass to get a circle?

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/james_bond100/6b8ka5Lt/17/) for my js, html and .csv file. I would really appreciate anyone who can tell me what value should I pass to the function.

Comment: your jsfiddle is not complete, can you post the complete project with csv html?

Comment: Hi @cal_br_mar, thanks for notifying me about the incompleteness of my JSFiddle. I've updated my JSFiddle.

Comment: post the new fiddle link. What do you want to see? What should be the circle and what text do you want? There is no `mean_time_in_hospital` in your `datapoints`

Comment: Sorry I've updated the JSFiddle again. The mean_time_in_hospital is generated in the nest() function. The size of the circle will depends on the number patients associated to the age_group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grouped data `groupByAgeAndtime` using d3.nest() has to be used on your simulation and circle drawing.

Note that your `radiusScale` now gets the correct value to be mapped to chosen range `range([50, 150]);`

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("x", d3.forceX(width / 2).strength(0.05))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(height / 2).strength(0.05))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
    return radiusScale(d.mean_time_in_hospital);
  }))


simulation.nodes(Object.values(groupByAgeAndtime))
  .on('tick', ticked)
```

The same for the circles, and the circles radius now matches the simulation radius

```
var circles = svg.selectAll(".artist")
  .data(Object.values(groupByAgeAndtime))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "artist")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return radiusScale(d.mean_time_in_hospital)
  })
  .attr("fill", "lightblue")
  .on("click", function(d) {
    console.log(d)
  })
```

Here is the functional example, your text still needs to be implemented.
I've pasted your csv data here https://hastebin.com/raw/pasacimala

```js
(function() {
  var width = 800,
    height = 350;

  var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)
   .attr("preserveAspectRatio","xMidYMid meet")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");

  // import csv file
  d3.csv("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://hastebin.com/raw/pasacimala")
    .then(function(d) {
      //data preprocessing
      d.forEach(e => {
       e.age = e.age.replace("[", "").replace(")", "");
       e.time_in_hospital = + e.time_in_hospital;
   });
      return d; //must return something
    })
    .then((data, err) => ready(err, data))

  function ready(error, datapoints) {

    var groupByAgeAndtime = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {
        return d.age;
      })
      //.key(function(d) { return d.time_in_hospital; })
      .rollup(function(v) {
        return {
          mean_time_in_hospital: d3.mean(v, function(d) {
            return d.time_in_hospital;
          })
        }
      })
      .object(datapoints); //specify the dataset used



    /**************************************** SCALING PART **************************************************/

    var radiusScale = d3.scaleSqrt()
      .domain([d3.min(Object.values(groupByAgeAndtime), function(d) {
        return d.mean_time_in_hospital;
      }), d3.max(Object.values(groupByAgeAndtime), function(d) {
        return d.mean_time_in_hospital;
      })])
      .range([50, 150]);

 /*    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      //console.log(d3.entries(groupByAgeAndtime)[i]["key"]);
      console.log(d3.entries(groupByAgeAndtime)[i]["value"]);
    } */
 console.log(Object.values(groupByAgeAndtime))
    // STUCK HERE
    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force("x", d3.forceX(width / 2).strength(0.05))
      .force("y", d3.forceY(height / 2).strength(0.05))
      .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
        return radiusScale(d.mean_time_in_hospital);
      }))

    // END OF STUCK HERE

    var circles = svg.selectAll(".artist")
      .data(Object.values(groupByAgeAndtime))
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "artist")
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return radiusScale(d.mean_time_in_hospital)
      })
      .attr("fill", "lightblue")
      .on("click", function(d) {
        console.log(d)
      })

    // append = add something
    // text
    var texts = svg.selectAll('.text')
      .data(Object.keys(groupByAgeAndtime))
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .text(e => e)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr('color', 'black')
      .attr('font-size', '13')

    simulation.nodes(Object.values(groupByAgeAndtime))
      .on('tick', ticked)

    function ticked() {
      texts
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.x
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return d.y
        })

      circles
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          return d.x
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return d.y
        })



    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Woww!! You've actually re-write my code! It really works man!! Thanks!! However, the text couldn't come out because it's data is **Object.keys(groupByAgeAndtime)** but the simulation.node are using **Object.values(groupByAgeAndtime)**. Any tips for me to deal with that? Can **Object.entries** solve that problem?

Comment: Which text do you want to include? have a look on **groupByAgeAndtime** it doesn't have any text, you have to build it on your nest() function, then you grouped that is used for all methods, circle, text, and simulation.

Comment: I actually just want to display the **age** from the **groupByAgeAndtime**. It's from this -->  var groupByAgeAndtime = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {
        return d.age;
      }).... It would be something like this: 0-10 , 10-20 etc. Is that possible to do so?

Comment: make your nodes data separated instead of using Object.entries, or Object.keys, then add the label there ```var nodesData = Object.entries(groupByAgeAndtime).map(function(e){
      return {
          label: e[0],
          mean_time_in_hospital: e[1].mean_time_in_hospital
      }
    })``` and change your text to `.text(e => e.label)`